# Flip rows in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working on a connect four game on python and encountered a problem while trying to print my board. I would like to display my board such that the row at the top appears at the bottom when the board is printed.

eg:

`[1,0,0,0]
[0,1,0,0]
[0,0,1,0]` becomes

`[0,0,1,0]
[0,1,0,0]
[1,0,0,0]`
I have tried `np.flip and np.flipud` but that does not seem to work.
This is my current code

`def display_board(game):
    for i in range (game.rows):
        print(np.flip(game.mat[i,: :-1]))`

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to move only the first row to the last position, use [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html). If you want to reverse the order of the rows, it should be [`np.flip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html)/[`np.flipud`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) or indexing with `[::-1]`.

Comment: Just print `game.mat[game.rows-i]`

Comment: I tried that but got this error IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10

Comment: Show us how you use `flipud` or `[::-1]` and tell us what is wrong.  Just from your description it's hard to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: The original board looks like this when I print with my code, assuming two rows and four columns are printed `[0,1,0,0] , [0,0,0,0]`. When I print np.flipud(game.mat[i,: :-1]), I get a board that looks like this `[0,0,1,0] , [0,0,0,0]`. When I print (game.mat[:: -1]), I get a board that looks like this       `[[0,1,0,0] , [0,0,0,0]],[[0,1,0,0] , [0,0,0,0]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use array indexing. For example:

```
I = np.eye(3)
```

`I` is:

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

and

```
I[::-1]
```

returns

```
array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```